# ASCII code decode to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on this question and have my answer as following?

> A string is encoded by performing the following sequence of actions:
>
> 1. Replace each character with its ASCII value representation.
> 2. Reverse the string.
>
> For example, the table below shows the conversion from the string  "`HelloWorld`" to the ASCII string "`7210110810811187111114108100`":
>
> ```
> Character
> H  e   l   l   o    W  o   r   l   d
> ASCII Value
> 72 101 108 108 111  87 111 114 108 100
> ```
>
> The ASCII string is then reversed to get the encoded string "`0018014111117811180180110127`".
>
> The characters in encoded string are within the range 10 - 126 which include special characters.

**Example:**
`asciidecode('111111')` => `'\x0b\x0b\x0b'` or `'oo'`
because we can split the
input `111111` (after reverse back: '111111') like `11,11,11` or `111,111`

```
from typing import List

def asciidecode(self, s: str) -> List:
    if not s: return ''
    s = s[::-1]
    n = len(s)
    ch_map = {str(i): chr(i) for i in range(10, 127)}
    dp = [[''] for _ in range(n + 1)]
    dp[2] = [ch_map[s[:2]]] if s[:2] in ch_map else ''
    dp[3] = [ch_map[s[:3]]] if s[:3] in ch_map else ''
    dp[4] = [dp[2][0] + ch_map[s[2:4]]] if s[2:4] in ch_map else ''
    for i in range(5, n + 1):
        p1 = s[i - 2: i]
        p2 = s[i - 3: i]
        tmp = []
        if p1 in ch_map:
            tmp += [i + ch_map[p1] for i in dp[i - 2]]
        if p2 in ch_map:
            tmp += [i + ch_map[p2] for i in dp[i - 3]]
        dp[i] = tmp
    return dp[-1]
```

Comment: `print(asciiencode('HelloWorld'))` doesn't work at all!

Comment: the question is input from a decode asciicode like "0018014111117811180180110127", need to write a function to get original string, but i will update question to make more clear

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I would have expected the decoding function to be called `asciidecode()` instead.

Comment: i see. wil update my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `return ''` doesn't have the type `List`.
2. `List` means `List[Any]`, you should use `List[str]`.
3. Your variable names are garbage.

   - `s` -> `string`
   - `n` -> `length`
   - `ch_map` -> `char_map` or `character_map`
   - `dp` -> what does this even mean?
   - `p1` -> `position_1`?
4. Don't put `return` statements on the same line as an `if`.
5. Again strings shouldn't be assigend to lists, yes you can iterate over them because they're both sequences. But they're not the same type. `[ch_map[s[:2]]] if s[:2] in char_map else ''`
6. `ch_map` should be a constant outside the function.
7. It's far easier to understand your code if it's written using recursion.
8. Recursion has some problems, and so it should be written in a way that allows you to easily convert it to a while loop.

```
CHAR_MAP = {str(i): chr(i) for i in range(10, 127)}


def asciidecode(string: str) -> List[str]:
    if not string:
        return []
    string = string[::-1]
    length = len(string)

    def inner(index):
        if index == length:
            yield ''
        else:
            for size in (2, 3):
                if length < index + size:
                    break
                letter = CHAR_MAP.get(string[index:index + size])
                if letter is not None:
                    for word in inner(index + size):
                        yield letter + word
    return list(inner(0))


def asciidecode_pre_while(string: str) -> List[str]:
    if not string:
        return []
    string = string[::-1]
    length = len(string)
    output = []

    def inner(index, word):
        if index == length:
            output.append(word)
            return

        for size in (2, 3):
            if length < index + size:
                break
            letter = CHAR_MAP.get(string[index:index + size])
            if letter is not None:
                inner(index + size, word + letter)
    inner(0, '')
    return output
```

From the second one it's easy to convert it to a while loop:

```
CHAR_MAP = {str(i): chr(i) for i in range(10, 127)}


def asciidecode(string: str) -> List[str]:
    if not string:
        return []
    string = string[::-1]
    length = len(string)
    output = []

    stack = [(0, '')]
    while stack:
        index, word = stack.pop()
        if index == length:
            output.append(word)
            continue

        for size in (2, 3):
            if length < index + size:
                break
            letter = CHAR_MAP.get(string[index:index + size])
            if letter is not None:
                stack.append((index + size, word + letter))
    return output
```

Comment: so what is time complexity?

Comment: @A.Lee When did you or I say anything about time complexity?

Comment: i mean for your while loop solution what is time complexity? O(2 ^ n)?

Comment: @A.Lee You've not answered my question.

Comment: i do not think I mention anything about time complexity on my post but want to know what is it for your while loop solution

Comment: @A.Lee It's complexities are time-\$O(2^d)\$ and memory-\$O(d^2)\$, where \$d\$ is the size of the largest decoded string.

Comment: @A.Lee Actually that's wrong. My memory is \$O(d2^d)\$ as the maximum output is \$2^d\$ values, each with a size of \$d\$. Your complexities are time-\$O(n\sqrt{2}^n)\$, memory-\$O(n^2 \sqrt{2}^n)\$. Converting mine in terms of \$n\$, for comparison, makes them time-\$O(\sqrt{2}^n)\$ and memory-\$O(n\sqrt{2}^n)\$.

Comment: why my complexities is (2‾√)? i loop through 0 to n the worst case is I can only split 2 digit each time until end...running time is O(n/2) => O(n), no?

Comment: @A.Lee For short hand `a:b` means "`dp[a]`'s worst case is b". Worst case sizes are `2:1`, `3:1`, `4:1`, `5:2`, `6:2`, `7:3`, `8:4`, `9:5`, `10:7`, `11:9`... Simplifying the pattern by changing segments of 3 to 2, you get `2:1`, `4:2`, `6:4`, `8:8`, `10:16`. Which is \$2^\frac{n}{2}\$ aka \$\sqrt{2}^n\$. Whilst this ignores segments of 3, it's still accurate in telling the magnitude. Since the worst case of `dp` is `dp[-1]` so \$O(\sqrt{2}^n)\$ and you loop through this list \$n\$ times it becomes \$O(n\sqrt{2}^n)\$.